# How do you create an if statement to check if many objects style == dispaly:none?

Tags: function, if-statement, call

I'm making a memory-match game in which you flip two cards over in order to get them to match.

I'm doing it with simple if statements as shown below:

```
if(click == 2)  //denotes two cards being clicked
{
    if(flippedArray[1].src === flippedArray[0].src)  // if click 1 == click 2 then refer to function 'delayMatch' which sets click 1 and 2 cards to not be displayed
    {
        window.setTimeout(function() { delayMatch() }, 500);        
        console.log("EQUAL");
        score = +25000;
    }
    else
    {
        window.setTimeout(function() { delayNoMatch() }, 500); // if click 1 != click 2 then display card.png 
        console.log("NOT EQUAL");
        score = -1999;
    }
        function delayMatch()  //function for matching pairs
    {
    flippedArray[0].style = "display:none;";
    flippedArray[1].style = "display:none;";

    }
        function delayNoMatch()  //function for non-matching pairs
    {
    flippedArray[0].src = "card.png";
    flippedArray[1].src = "card.png";   
    }


    click = 0;  // when clicked two cards set click back to zero    
}
```

As you can see if two cards match they're set to display:none.  What I'm trying to do is link to an "end game" html page once all 36 divs are set to display: none or I guess once the function delayMatch() has been called 18 times.

I'm completely at a loss as how I can do this.

my goal is something like this:

flippedArray[0] and flippedArray[1] is just a temporary array to check if the two cards currently in play are a match or not.

I was thinking something like:

```
endGameCounter =0;
    endGameCounter++; //in the matching if-statement

then    if(endGameCounter == 18)
    {
    location.href='link here'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function GameIsOver(){
  for (var i = 0; i < allCards.length; i++) {
    if(allCards[i].style.display === 'none')return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: flippedArray[0] and flippedArray[1] is just a temporary array to check if the two cards currently in play are a match or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one variable for count inside the page.
If you are doing it in JSP, [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm) can help you here.

use  to set a variable and just check the value time to time.

```
c:set var="COUNT" value="SOMETHING"/>
```